# Get all items of the last 15 minutes in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

As I come from RDBM background I am bit confuse with DynamoDB, how to write this query.

**Problem** : need to filter out those data which is more than 15 minutes.

I have created GSI with hashkey`materialType` and `createTime` (create time format `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`).

Now I have to write a java query which gives those values which is more than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using cli.

`:v1` should be the material type I'd that you are searching on.  `:v2` should be your epoch time in milliseconds for 30 mins ago which you will have to calculate.

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name mytable \
    --index-name myindex
    --key-condition-expression "materialType = :v1 AND create time > :v2" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{
    ":v1": {"S": "some id"},
    ":V2": {"N": "766677876567"}
}'
```